# Replace Excel Cell Value with Text Box Input in VBA Form

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a simple form in **Excel 201**0 in which I wish to replace the individual text string value in 11 cells in the cell range `B5 : B15`

I have used this code to test the first cell at `B5` which is referenced in `A5` by the Label Christian Name and I have labelled the text box on the form Christian_Input:

```
Private Sub Christian_Input_Change()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 1) = Christian_Input.Text
End Sub
```

When I enter a new text string in the form and run it, the form simply appears over my Sheet1 with the replacement text in the input text box but the text string in cell `B5` is neither highlighted or replaced.

Finally when I open the file the form is not visible.

Can anyone please advise what alterations I need to make.

Comment: How do you run the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B5:B15").value = Christian_Input.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("B5").select
```

Add the following to your "This Workbook" module to auto-start the form when you open the workbook (replace UserFormNameHere with the name of your form):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserFormNameHere.show   
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Sebastian, I regret that after modifying the code in my user form as appended below, it still does not overwrite the text in cell B5 on Sheet1. Should their be some form of cmdButton to action the overwriting of the cell? I am most grateful to you for your kind assistance.                                              Private Sub Christian_Input_Change()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:B15").Value = Christian_Input.Text
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Select
End Sub

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to write to "Sheet1" ? Are you meaning a different sheet?

Comment: You can try adding the code: `MsgBox Christian_Input.Text` to see if the text that you want in the cells are captured properly in the Input Box. If this doesn't show a message box with the text you need on the cells, it is a problem with the code for your input box